# Using Captcha to protect from denial attack

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, captcha

I am using *Asp.net FileUpload*. Should I use Captcha to protect form Denial attack?

I did not find any a famous web site doing so, and I wonder whether this is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very broad and risks being removed.

That said I think it depends on each individual case, if it's a publicly accessible form, it's certainly something you should consider.

SPAM is probably more of a concern that a DDOS attack.

Comment: I agree with Shaun, it depends on each case, and if you were using a public form for uploading then I'd, personally, be inclined to add a captcha check. Otherwise if there is security, such as logins, have the captcha check upon user account creation as you can filter out fake accounts at the root of any potential attacks.